# How to load CspParams in RSGCng

Tags: c#, rsa, rsacryptoserviceprovider

We are trying to load private key from container Name using cspParams in RSACng object. We don't see a direct way to load this and currently we are performing below workaround to load it from RSACryptoServiceProvider as shown below,

```
            using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams))
            {
                using(var rsaCng = new RSACng())
                {
                    rsaCng.ImportParameters(rsa.ExportParameters(true));
                    decryptedResult = rsaCng.Decrypt(encryotedText, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256)
                }
            }
```

Is this only way to do this or do we have any other direct way to load private key from container name in rsaCng object

Comment: What properties are you setting on the CspParameters?

Comment: @bartonjs Just the KeyContainerName                                                                                       var cspParams = new CspParameters { KeyContainerName = containerName };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CngProvider provider = new CngProvider("Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider");
using (CngKey key = CngKey.Open(containerName, provider))
using (RSA rsa = new RSACng(key))
{
    ...
}
```

Should work, the only time it gets confused is when you use the CAPI feature of having a different signing key and exchange key with the same name (the CNG-opening-CAPI tríes exchange then signature when doing a CAPI load... since you didn’t specify you’re using exchange).

Comment: Thanks @bartonjs that worked. It also worked without providing the provider and just containerName in Open method. What is significance of provider here or any documentation on that? Any insights on this specific provider, Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider

Comment: @TryingStuff it just means that the default provider (Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider) falls back to the software provider names in CAPI. The provider name I used is the default CAPI provider, it’s what you’ll probably see as PrpviderName if you read the CspKeyContainerInfo property on your existing RSACryptoServiceProvider key.

Comment: Thanks @bartonjs for clarification